# How to set keyboard layout such that it is easy to input email?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

How can I make it so that the user's keyboard is suited to inputting email info? I have found nothing on this online.

I should note that I want to do this programaticaly

Comment: Can you give more details? I guess that you are looking for this: .keyboardType = .emailAddress but please elaborate to understand better.

Comment: @Enrique that's exatly what I needed thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code you can do it with:

```
someTextField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
```

The best way would be to configure text field to expect email content:
In XCode interface builder, in Attributes inspector for Text input traits: Content type set value Email Address

[image]